# Room update query only update one row

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-update, android-room

I have a `Book` object with 3 primary keys (id, belongToTab, propertyOfUserId)

Say, I have a database of book like this:

> book1(id = 10162, belongToTab = 1, propertyOfUserId=896)
>
> book1(id = 10162, belongToTab = 0, propertyOfUserId=896)

In my `BookDao` interface I made a method like this:

```
@Query("UPDATE BOOK SET isArchived = 1 Where id in (:listId) and propertyOfUserId = :userId")
void updateBookArchived(List<Long> listId, long userId);
```

For testing, I only have one item (which is 10162) inside the `listId`. When this method is called, I extract the database and found out that only one row (the first with belongToTab = 1) is updated isArchived = 1. The other is still 0 (same as before)

But If I execute the query inside the sqlite browser:
`UPDATE BOOK SET isArchived = 1 Where id in (10162) and propertyOfUserId = 896` the result is perfect, 2 rows are update.

I tried passing both `List<Long>` and `Long[]` but no luck. Debugging the generated file `BookDao_Impl` I see the query string is like

> UPDATE BOOK SET isArchived = 1 Where id in (?) and propertyOfUserId = ?

(if list contains 3 items then it's `... Where id in (?,?,?) and ....`), so I guess passing the List into it is working.
I have no idea what was wrong.

Thank you for your valuable time.

**EDIT:**
I created a simple project to test the problem, and the query worked as expected. There must be another problem with the.... "structure" or something. I wish I knew what is the possible cause of this problem.

Comment: As you mentioned _"For testing, I only have one item"_ then why are you expecting that SQLite should update more than one rows? AFAIK in SQLite Browser for testing you can insert dummy records and test your query. Add more than one record into your database and try to update the rows.

Comment: I mean only one item in the id list, not one row. I expect it to update 2 row because both rows have the same `id` and the same `propertyOfUserId` and I don't care what `belongToTab` property is, just need it to have the provided `id` and `propertyOfUserId`

Answer (score 0):

That was silly. There was a new record from API which overwrite the last row.

I've struggled for 2 days, believing the API is correct. My bad.